# Scala: completing a Future when other Futures are completed

Tags: scala, future

I have references to n Future instances `f1,.....fn`. Is it possible to use `Future.apply` to create a Future that would complete only when at least one of the n Futures completes, without constantly checking their completion status, but instead by some more efficient way, maybe a callback?

Comment: @jwvh How do I make the wrapping Future complete when (at least) one of the element Futures is completed?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You wrote "at least one" but I read "the last one".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f1, ..., fn))
```

> [Asynchronously and non-blockingly returns a new Future to the result of the first future in the list that is completed.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#firstCompletedOf[T](futures:TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T])

Comment: Круто! Очень спасибо.